# SSIS (ASCII needed): "Code page is 1252 and is required to be 20127"

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a requirement to export a database to a tab-delimited file in the ASCII format. I am using derived columns to convert any Unicode strings to non-Unicode strings. For example, a former Unicode text stream is now casted as this:

```
(DT_TEXT,20127)incomingMessage
```

But SSIS is still looking for ANSI. I am still seeing an error at the Flat File Destination:

```
The code page on input column <column_name> is 1252 and is required to be 20127.
```

This happens for **any** column in the table, not just Unicode ones.

This is what I have been doing to ensure ASCII is used:

- In the Flat File Connection Manager, used Code page "20127 (US-ASCII)"
- Used a Derived Column to cast data types
- In the OLE DB source, set the default code page to 20127

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using the Data Conversion task?  Connect the Flat File task to the Data Conversion and then change the metadata on the fly to suit your needs. You should be able to delete the derived column task if you change the metadata to handle the unicode issues in the data conversion task.  Then you can process the records accordingly into the OLE DB Source without issues.